# Why is Haskell giving "ambiguous type variable" error?

Tags: list, function, haskell, recursion, quickcheck

A past paper problem asked me; to define a function p :: [a] -> [a] that swaps every two items in a list. Your function should swap the first with the second item, the third
with the fourth, and so on. define one by list comprehension another by recursion.

Well this is what I came up with:

```
import Test.QuickCheck
p :: [a] -> [a]
p [] = []
p xs = concat [ [y,x] | ((x,y),i) <- zip (zip xs (tail xs)) [1..], odd i]
q :: [a] -> [a]
q [] = []
q (x:y:zs) | even (length zs) = [y,x] ++ q zs
           | otherwise = error "The list provided is not of even length"
prop_2 xs = even (length xs) ==> p xs == q xs
check2 = quickCheck prop_2
```

The functions work fine, but I wanted to check if the two are identical, so I put the quickCheck below; but this gives me an error for some reason saying
"ambiguous type variable [a0] arising from the use of prop_2"

I just don't understand what's wrong here, I looks perfectly sensible to me...
what exactly is Haskell complaining??

Comment: Imagine you're GHC.  What type of list do you generate for the QuickCheck test?

Answer (score 9):

Let's start by commenting out `check2` and asking GHCi what the type of `prop_2` is:

```
*Main> :t prop_2
prop_2 :: Eq a => [a] -> Property
```

Ok, so the way you've written `prop_2`, it works for lists of any element type that is in the equality class.

Now, you want to pass `prop_2` to the `quickCheck` function. Let's look at the type of `quickCheck` next:

```
*Main> :t quickCheck
quickCheck :: Testable prop => prop -> IO ()
```

This function actually has an immensely general type. It works on anything that's in the `Testable` class. So how does this `Testable` class work? There are a couple of base instances here, for example:

```
instance Testable Bool
instance Testable Property  -- this is a simplification, but it's more or less true
```

These instances are defined in the QuickCheck library and tell you that you can quick-check
constant Booleans as well as elements of type Property.

Now, testing properties that do not depend on any inputs isn't particularly interesting. The interesting instance is this one:

```
instance (Arbitrary a, Show a, Testable prop) => Testable (a -> prop)
```

What this says is that if you know how to generate random values of a particular type (`Arbitrary a`) and how to show values of that type (`Show a`), then you can also test functions from that type `a` to an already testable type `prop`.

Why? Because that's how QuickCheck operates. In such a situation, QuickCheck will consult the `Arbitrary` instance in order to come up with random test cases of type `a`, apply the function to each of them, and check if the outcome is positive. If any of the tests fails, it will print a message informing you about the test failure, and it will print the test case (that's why there's a `Show` requirement, too).

Now, in our situation this means that we should be able to quick-check `prop_2`: it is a function that results in a `Property`. The important thing is that the function argument (of type `[a]` as long as `Eq a` holds) is a member of class `Arbitrary` and a member of class `Show`.

Here we arrive at the source of the error. The information available is not sufficient to make that conclusion. As I said in the beginning, `prop_2` works for lists of any element type that admits equality. There's no built-in rule that says that all these type are in `Arbitrary` and `Show`. But even if there was, what kind of lists should QuickCheck generate? Should it generate lists of Booleans, lists of unit type, lists of functions, lists of characters, lists of integers? So many options, and the choice of element type may well affect whether you find a bug or not. (Consider that GHC would pick the unit type `()` with just one element. Then your property would hold for any two functions `p` and `q` that preserve the input lists' length, regardless of whether they have your desired swapping property or not.)

This is why you need to provide extra type information to GHC so that it can resolve which element type to use for the list. Doing so is simple enough. You can either annotate `prop_2` itself:

```
prop_2 :: [Integer] -> Property
```

Or, if you don't want that (because you might want to run the tests on different kinds of lists without reimplementing `prop_2`), you can add a type annotation when calling `quickCheck`:

```
check2 = quickCheck (prop_2 :: [Integer] -> Property)
```

Now the code compiles, and we can run `check2`:

```
Main*> check2
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for answering! But I still don't get it(I'm sorry I'm a total beginner, just started programming in uni which is kicking my arse now...), so is it that Haskell has no idea what "prop_2" is so I have to tell it?                                                                                      >prop_2 xs = even (length xs) ==> p xs == q xs                         takes [a] and turns it to an Int and then gives a Bool, so                >p :: [a] -> Int -> Bool                                              but I'm not sure what to state after this for "==> p xs == q xs" ...

Comment: @Brad I've significantly expanded the answer. I hope this helps.